# Springboot I/O error connection refused error using resttemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

how to fix this error, i am using docker-compose to run two basic CRUD webservices, and i need to get Object from one of them, it used to work when one service was running using docker another from intellij (Spring boot) 
`"message": "I/O error on GET request for \"http://localhost:80/api/parts/1/\": Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)",`
I can open the localhost:80/api/parts/1 and it returns 
 `[
  {
    "id": 1, 
    "manufacturer": "AMD", 
    "name": "Ryzen 5 3600", 
    "price": "181.00", 
    "type": "CPU"
  }
]`
Docker-compose files: 
   `version: '3.7'
services:
    articles-service:
        container_name: articles-service
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
        volumes:
        - .:/service
        networks:
            - ws_bridge
    computer-parts:
        build: ./comp_parts
        command: python app.py
        ports:
            - "80:5000"
        volumes:
        - .:/service
        container_name: external
        networks:
            - ws_bridge
networks:
    ws_bridge:`

second docker-compose file:

`version: '3.7'
networks:
    default:
        external:
            name: ws_bridge
services:
    web:
        build: .
        command: python app.py
        ports:
            - "5005:5005"
        volumes:
            - .:/service
        container_name: comp_parts`

Here's the code

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    ResponseEntity<PcPart[]> response =
            restTemplate.getForEntity(
                    "http://localhost:80/api/parts/1",
                    PcPart[].class);
    PcPart[] parts = response.getBody();
    Article article = getArticle(articleId);
    article.addParts(parts[0]);
```

Comment: It would help if you show us your docker-compose files as it seems they are not in the same network.

Comment: Hello, added docker-compose files